# Transaction does not work

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a procedure where I change the values of 2 tables. Messagebox
   shows the error and transaction does not roll back. `MySqlException` catches the error. But `ExecuteNonQuery` returns 1 row
   affected!!!

Transaction writes the values into two calls before but
   not where it catches the error. When I debugged I saw that this error
   is DateTime.Now gives a value of `'2013-11-15 12:04:21.656'` to
   variable. However this variable in the format of DateTime et declared
   so at the begining of procedure.

### [Here is my code](http://www.turcguide.com/stack/updatemacaron.txt)

Comment: --------->>>>>>>>>>>> "You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

Comment: Yes I don't how it can because it's unpredictible date format. But the problem transaction does not roll back after the mysqlexception catch the error.

Comment: I understood nothig about off-topic reason. It's a question with fully described explanation. However I resolved my probleme  as mentionned by @Mitch Wheat, after a work of 2 days on sqlfiddle. It works. I would share the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're not setting the command's transaction:

```
cmd.Transaction = trans;
```

(needs to be on every command - yes, this is tedious)

Additionally, you might want to ensure you only have a single place to commit/rollback, to avoid issue. For example:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(PublicVariables.cs))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            // ...command the first
            // ...command the second
            // ...command the third
            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            ShowMessage(ex.Message); // etc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the line but the values change before the roll back in 2 tables not in the last one. Is it normal that DateTime.Now assign a values as '2013-11-15 12:04:21.656' ?  to a variables defined as DateTime format ?

Comment: @IsmailGunes can you rephrase the first part of that sentence? I cannot parse what you are saying

Comment: @IsmailGunes re the second part: a datetime is a *number*, not a string. It is not clear to me where you are seeing it as a string, so I can't comment.

Comment: In my link as you can see I make a to writing into 2 tables rollback normally must roll back. And the error which causes the end of transaction is where a value of '2013-11-15 12:04:21.656'is assigned. '2013-11-15 12:04:21.656' that's the format of DateTime.Now or '2013-11-15 12:04:21' ?

Comment: It's like your exemple my transaction but without using "using" but I will try with using now.

Comment: "see I make a to writing into 2 tables rollbank normally must roll back" - nope, sorry, I simply can't understand what you are trying to say in that sentence. And to say again: *DateTime.Now does not have a format; it is a number*. I wonder what the defined column type of `up_date` is.

Comment: up_date is formated in MySql with phpmyadmin DATETIME in server. It's a column name n my table

Comment: Same result the first ExecutNonQuery is executed but the 2 fallowing are not executed (rolled back)

Comment: Perhaps myserver does not support multiple transactions. I will ask them.

Comment: @IsmailGunes you only create one transaction

Comment: Sory I meant one transaction for multiple tables. Which is the objective of a transaction. I have defined only one transaction as in my link. When your question about time it's in my link where there is MySqlCommand cmd2 same line where I assgin the values of Mycrdate to up_date @Mycrdate get a value DateTime format. But mysql exeption show it with an extra number "656"